# Use a numerical method to approximate the roots of $x^2-1000.01 x+10=0$.

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification

> **Problem**: Find the roots of the following equation with calculations of four significant digits. Then use a method to find the roots of the equation with the maximum accuracy.
>   $$x^2-1000.01 x+10=0$$

Here's what I've got so far:

$\Delta=1000^2 - 4(1.000)(10.00) = 999960\Rightarrow \sqrt{\Delta}=999.9800$

Four significant digits $\Longrightarrow\sqrt{\Delta} = 1000$

$\Rightarrow x=\dfrac{1000\pm 1000}{2} = 1000 \text{  and  } 0$

Have I got the first part of the problem right?

For the second part, can I use *fixed point iteration* method? If yes, how? Can I possibly do the following?

$x(x-1000.01)+10=0\Rightarrow g(x)=x=\dfrac{10}{1000.01-x}$

And then, $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$.

Comment: What does maximum accuracy mean? And for your first part, are you claiming that $x = 0$ is a root? It's very clearly not. (Sticking in $x = 0$ gives $10 = 0$)

Comment: @mixedmath By max accuracy, I mean using any method other than direct. And, since I've changed the numbers in my calculations to meet that four-digit significance, probably that's one of the errors caused (x=0 is a root)! :|

Comment: I still don't know what max accuracy means. You can get arbitrary accuracy using Newton's method or fixed point iteration, for instance.

Comment: After computing the largest root $x_1=1000$ the second is just $x_2=10/1000=0.01$ exact to four digits.

Answer (score 3):

You have a quadratic equation $x^2-px+q=0$ with $|q|\ll 
p$. This causes no numerical problem for the root
$$x_1={1\over2}\bigl(p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}\bigr)\ ,$$
but for the other root $x_2={1\over2}\bigl(p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}\bigr)$. Here is a way out: By Vieta's theorem one has $x_1\>x_2=q$. It follows that
$$x_2={q\over x_1}$$
at once leads to the desired accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The [Numerical Recipies in C](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-6.pdf) shows the following way to compute roots of a quadratics robustly
$$
q = -\frac{1}{2}\left[b + \operatorname{sign}(b)\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\right]\\
x_1 = \frac{q}{a} \qquad x_2 = \frac{c}{q}
$$